# How to find out when my windows XP account was reset?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

My sister told me that her windows XP account has been reset but she did not reset it personally. By reset, I mean all her documents and settings are gone but the account still exists. She is not sure if this is a virus or if one of her friends have done it as a prank without realizing that everything would be gone forever.

Is there a way to find out what happened using event viewer or some other logging mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about how to find out, but I believe that resetting your password (as opposed to changing your password) can cause this deletion.

Comment: look in the users folder and inside every username folder that you see if you dont see your files anywhere inside then its gone. You can also try restoring that might bring things back.

Comment: I use the create date of the user folder as my indicator. If it's a significant time in the past, then you're looking at a possible Windows restore that was done.